# Reverse an array of numbers

Tags: c

How can I reverse an array of integers from left to right in C programming?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    N=4;

    for(k=1; k<=N; k=k+1);
        printf("%d",flip(k));
}
```

Example:
k = [1,2,3,4] flip should give k=[4,3,2,1]
k  is a number array

Comment: what you want to flip?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "flipping"? What would you want the result to be after calling this `flip` function?

Comment: At the very least please provide some sample input and output to clarify your question.

Comment: This is second unclear question from you. Please put some efforts before asking here

Comment: Example: 1234 --> 4321.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Is that your guess, or are you somehow associated with the OP?

Comment: @Bart I was over confident LOL.. I'm not associated..

Comment: Yes Maroun was right 1234 -> 4321

Comment: The algorithm should not be that hard... Do you want to get the actual numeric value of the reversed number, or just the string representation?

Comment: The code that does what is asked: http://ideone.com/IIK0cc

Comment: Reversing the digits can be done in two ways: One is to simply convert the number to a string, reverse the string, and convert back to an integer. The other is to use division and modulo to get the digits one by one, and multiplication and addition to put the new value together.

Comment: @user2240149 Will [this](http://ideone.com/Of2QnN) work for you ?

Comment: Your question is very misleading. In the example code `k` is a single `int` but your comments below imply that `k` should be an array. Can you edit your question so it makes sense?

Comment: Even after your edit, the question is still non-sensical. You show `k` as a single integer, yet seem to want to treat it as an array, have `N` be some harcoded value that represents who-knows-what, and you seem unwilling to make even the minimum effort needed to fix these issues that have been pointed out to you.

Comment: @user2240149 Please read my answer.

Comment: @user2240149 Does my edit represent what you were trying to say? If not, please roll it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your question is vague and contradictory. For example, is `k` a single integer, as the code you include in your question suggests, or is `k` an array of integers, as your talk about "vectors" suggests? Furthermore, do you want to reverse the *integer* or do you want to reverse the *array*? Those are two very different questions. For future reference, if you want to get a good answer, you should *ask a good question*; and showing some of your work wouldn't hurt either.

Anyways, diatribe aside, here's the code to reverse an array in place. There's no error checking so if you call it the wrong way... well, you're on your own:

```
void flip(int *array,  // the array to reverse
          int count)   // the number of elements in the array
{
    int i = 0, tmp;

    while(i != count / 2)
    {
        tmp = array[i];    
        array[i] = array[count - i - 1];
        array[count - i - 1] = tmp;

        i++;
    }
}
```

For a sample of how to use this function, check out [this sample program I rigged up](http://ideone.com/rw48oB).

Answer (score 2):

Declare `N` as `int` (whereas `k` not needed). Print remainder by 10 in a loop and decrement `N = N/ 10` each time, try following code:

```
for(; N; N = N/10) 
       printf(" %d", N % 10);
```

Loop runs till N != 0.

It doesn't reverse number, but just print reverse.

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to reverse the numbers.

Comment: @user2240149 If you want check rest of two solutions by  Mr.32 and xanatos

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just google for such simple problem...!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n, reverse = 0;

   printf("Enter a number to reverse\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   while (n != 0)
   {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + n % 10;
      n = n / 10;
   }

   printf("Reverse of entered number is = %d\n", reverse);     
   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
root@jeegar:~# gcc test.c
root@jeegar:~# ./a.out 
Enter a number to reverse
1234
Reverse of entered number is = 4321
```

Comment: k ia a number array [1,2,3,4] i.e a vector and i want to reverse it so the array becomes [4,3,2,1]. Thanks though

Comment: @user2240149 thats a complete different thing. You should ask different question for that. For your asked question we have answered.

Comment: the for loop gives k as a number array in the question. Thanks for your input

Comment: the answers flip around a number but not an array of numbers.

Comment: first you have asked only for flip number then we have answered and now you changed your question so i suggested to ask new question for that. So for this question you should accept any answer.

Comment: @Mr.32 Please do not ask users to accept a specific answer. Many users have offered solutions that do exactly what yours does.

Comment: @SweetieBelle yea you are right but I have used word "any answer". But since all answer have same answer then i should not say that. But now can not edit my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The code you asked:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k = 0;
    int n = 1234;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        k *= 10;
        k += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    printf("%d", k);

    return 0;
}
```

From here it's easy to change it to a function. Note that it won't work correctly for numbers "near" the maximum value of an int.

Ideone of the code: http://ideone.com/IIK0cc

Comment: k ia a number array [1,2,3,4]  i.e a vector and i wabt to reverse it so the array becomes [4,3,2,1]

Comment: @user2240149 please specify in question That you have array.

Comment: @user2240149 As other have told you, the question with an array is a different question. You should learn to do correct *and* complete questions, and not going around wasting time of the persons.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**.  Just saw your revision that says the problem is to reverse an `int` array, not just a number. Well, faugh. That's a lot easier. And since this is C, you should use pointers. Anything else is not C.  :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse (int ary[], int size);

int main (void) {
    int ary[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int size = sizeof (ary) / sizeof (ary[0]);

    reverse (ary, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf ("%d ", ary[i]);

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}


void reverse (int ary[], int size) {
    int* startPtr;
    int* endPtr;
    int temp;

    startPtr = ary;
    endPtr = ary + size - 1;

    while (endPtr > startPtr) {
        temp = *startPtr;
        *startPtr = *endPtr;
        *endPtr = temp;
        startPtr++;
        endPtr--;
    }
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int flip(int k) { 
  int new = 0;

  while (k > 0) { 
    // Take the last digit and add it to the front of new   
    new = (new * 10) + k % 10;

    // Divide by ten to drop the last digit of k
    k = k / 10;
  }

  return new;
}
```

Comment: Although it's `c`, I wouldn't suggest to use the name `new`

Answer (score 0):

### It looks like you're trying to reverse an array, not a number

In which case, assuming `source` is your current array, `SIZE` is a constant with the size of `source` allocated to it, and `destination` is your target array, you can use this:

```
for (is = SIZE - 1, id = 0; is >= 0; is--, id++) {
    destination[id] = source[is];
}
```

[Working demo](https://eval.in/46422).

**If you want to replace `source`s contents...**

If you want to replace `source` instead of duplicating it in reverse, do this and then assign `destination` to `source`:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++) {
    destination[counter] = source[counter];
}
```

Comment: Question is about C, as mentioned in tags and the text.

Comment: @jku Op mentioned vector in a comment so assumed C++.

Comment: @SweetieBelle how can you "assign" a destination to a source, if your source is something like `int k[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`? This answer is, *at best*, half-baked.

Comment: @Nik `for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++) destination[counter] = source[counter];` -- For anyone who knows C, it's not exactly complex.

Comment: @SweetieBelle I'd argue that's not an assignment. And why even go to all this trouble to begin with? In place swapping is a better approach.

Comment: @NikBougalis It's technically `SIZE` assignments, but that's being pedantic. As I don't know whether he wants to end up with one array or two I don't know what the better approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing an array in C needs you to define a method that accepts the integer array as a pointer parameter and its size as a second parameter then reverse the elements such that the last element becomes the first and so on and so forth.

```
void reverseArray(int * arr, int size){
    int start =0;
    int end = size -1;
    while(start<end){
        //swapping the elements
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        //move the indices towards the center
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```